# extracting 2D array from 4D array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a 4D array in matlab something like this,

```
test(:,:,1,1) =

     0


test(:,:,2,1) =

     0


test(:,:,3,1) =

     0


test(:,:,4,1) =

     0


test(:,:,5,1) =

     0


test(:,:,1,2) =

     0


test(:,:,2,2) =

     0


test(:,:,3,2) =

     0


test(:,:,4,2) =

     0


test(:,:,5,2) =

     0


test(:,:,1,3) =

     0


test(:,:,2,3) =

     0


test(:,:,3,3) =

     0


test(:,:,4,3) =

     0


test(:,:,5,3) =

     0


test(:,:,1,4) =

     0


test(:,:,2,4) =

     0


test(:,:,3,4) =

     0


test(:,:,4,4) =

     0


test(:,:,5,4) =

     0


test(:,:,1,5) =

     0


test(:,:,2,5) =

     0


test(:,:,3,5) =

     0


test(:,:,4,5) =

     0


test(:,:,5,5) =

     0

K>> test

test(:,:,1,1) =

     0


test(:,:,2,1) =

     0


test(:,:,3,1) =

     0


test(:,:,4,1) =

     0


test(:,:,5,1) =

     0


test(:,:,1,2) =

     0


test(:,:,2,2) =

     0


test(:,:,3,2) =

     0


test(:,:,4,2) =

     0


test(:,:,5,2) =

     0


test(:,:,1,3) =

     0


test(:,:,2,3) =

     0


test(:,:,3,3) =

     0


test(:,:,4,3) =

     0


test(:,:,5,3) =

     0


test(:,:,1,4) =

     0


test(:,:,2,4) =

     0


test(:,:,3,4) =

     0


test(:,:,4,4) =

     0


test(:,:,5,4) =

     0


test(:,:,1,5) =

     0


test(:,:,2,5) =

     0


test(:,:,3,5) =

     0


test(:,:,4,5) =

     0


test(:,:,5,5) =

     0
```

Now I want to get an array, something like this

```
ans =

     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
```

Is there a simple way to convert the dimentions.
I am very much new to multidimensional arrays in Matlab.
Please let me know if anyone knows of any solution.

Comment: @Daniel Alright. Apologies to all. I'll delete my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`squeeze`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) function, it will return a matrix of size [5 4] when you input a matrix of size [1 1 5 4]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me know if you happen to know the same modification with the help of reshape command, that would be one more help. Regards

Comment: If you take a look at the question marked as duplicate (top of this page) you can find an example in one of the answers.